# Java Reflection getDeclaredMethod(...) Returning Null

Tags: java, reflection, syntax

I have imported the fully qualified name of the class and created an instance of the class. I then proceeded to acquire the private method name of the class:

```
InvokeCallWebservice invokeCallWebservice = new InvokeCallWebservice();

Method method = null;

try {
     method = invokeCallWebservice.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("Fully Qualified Class Name.getURL", String.class);
} 
catch (SecurityException e) {
     System.out.println(e.getCause());
} 
catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
     System.out.println(e.getCause());
}

    System.out.println(method.getName());
```

An exception is thrown because method is null. I am not sure the reason which could be the class exists in a different project and package or because I need to specify the second argument as many times as there are parameters in the method.  Can I actually invoke this on a private method?

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: InvokeCallWebservice.getURL(java.lang.String)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1937)
at com.geico.debug.Debug.main(Debug.java:39)
```

Comment: `Fully Qualified Class Name.getURL`. No, just the name of the method.

Comment: Also print the stack trace and post it here.

Comment: You might want to post the method in question as well. Does it have a `String` parameter?

Comment: The method in question has 5 Class.String parameters whose definition within the same project but a different package is: `private void getURL(String IPNumber, String ClaimNumber, String EventID, String UserEmail, String logId)`

Comment: Then you need to use `getDeclaredMethod("getURL", String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class);` to match its parameter types. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you and I have already performed this after realizing that I only have one such String.class parameter listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the class first, and with that class, get the method you want to get, only using the method name and parameters.

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("package.ClassIWant");

Method myMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getURL", String.class);
```

Comment: Tried this using the fully qualified name. The class is in the same Project but a different package than where I am setting my Method reference.  I got the class from the fully qualified name but am still unable to get the private method.

Comment: It works now.  I needed to `Class clazz = Class.getForName("Class Name");` and then `Method m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getURL", String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class)` and then finally `m.setAccessible(true)` & `Object o = m.invoke(instance, arguments)`.  I did not have all parameter arguments listed out when trying to get the method name.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Class#getDeclaredMethod(String, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) method javadoc states

> The `name` parameter is a `String` that specifies the simple name of the desired method

The simple name being just the name of the method as it appears in the source code, not qualified with the class it belongs to.

`getDeclaredMethod()` will throw a `NoSuchMethodException` if no such (named) method exists. In your case, you just print the cause, but still try to use the `method` variable even if it wasn't assigned. So it remains `null` and you get a NPE.

---

If your method takes 5 `String` arguments, then you need to use

```
getDeclaredMethod("getURL", String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class);
```

to match all its parameter types.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
Method method = ClassName.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, methodParameters);
```

Here `methodName` is the name of the method and `methodParameters` is the the parameter array.
Change it to:

```
method = invokeCallWebservice.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("methodName", String.class);
```

Where `methodName` is your method name.

For more details please read  [this](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java/lang/Class/getDeclaredMethod(String%20name,...%20parameterTypes).html) doc.

Comment: Tried this already.  The class whose private method I want direct access to through Reflection is in a different package than where I am  setting my Method reference.  I am still receiving an exception for no such method found.